# Rendering 3D timezones KML on a 2D map

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, kml, 3d, google-earth

I'm trying to render a KML layer (with timezones) in Google Maps API v3. The KML layer works fine in 3D (in Google Earth), but when I render it in 2D, the timezone lines that meet at the North Pole are spread out in a really weird way:

[image: Google Maps rendering]

Here is the correct rendering in 3D:

[image: Google Earth rendering]

How do I get fix that weird spread?

Answer (score 4):

In Google Maps, a Mercator projection is used that cuts off around 84 North and South. Try densifying the lines (add vertices) up to where the cut-off is.

Comment: @MrKennedy: Thanks! How do I do that?

Comment: @Maxim, sorry, no idea! I only use ArcGIS (I work at Esri). In it, I would just edit the data and insert vertices, or maybe look at a densify tool.

Comment: You can create a polygon that stops at 84 North/South and clip it. Then the lines will not cross. But you will need two kmls one for GE and the other for GMAPS - it's a 3D projection on a 2D flat surface thing causing the issue.